# Media Query troubles?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm new to the great world of web development. My issue is making my float change from float left to float none on media queries.What I want to accomplish is making my 3 images in the body change from horizontal to vertical. I'm trying to make my site responsive but every time I put in float none at max width 700px...no dice. Please help!
At this pint I'm typing for no reason do to the fact that this website states I need more detail in my post smh.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/**************
Section one
**************/

#section-one-container {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section-one {
  float: left;
  width: 31.25%;
  margin-right: .833%;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}


/***********
Media Q
***********/

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .section-one {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="section-one-container">
    <div class="section-one">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/opensourceforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/mysql-queries-1.jpg?resize=600%2C381">
      </figure>
      <h1>Questions</h1>
      <p>I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section-one">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/opensourceforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/mysql-queries-1.jpg?resize=600%2C381">
      </figure>
      <h1>Questions</h1>
      <p>I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section-one">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/opensourceforu.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/mysql-queries-1.jpg?resize=600%2C381">
      </figure>
      <h1>Questions</h1>
      <p>I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question,I have question</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: your code work fines

Comment: I wish you was telling the truth. I just tried it. it's not working.

Comment: Lol for some reason it works on here but it doesn't work when I pull it up locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP's comment in question:**

> Lol for some reason it works on here but it doesn't work when I pull
>   it up locally

it means you are missing the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), add it to your `head`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**OP's comment in answer:**

> The media query works when I put display none but when I put float
>   none it doesn't work. Yet it works when I uploaded it here

you have some issue with specificity, this property(`float`) is being overruled somewhere else, you need to be more specific , like `.parent .section {float:none}`,

Comment: The media query works when I put display none but when I put float none it doesn't work. Yet it works when I uploaded it here

Comment: I found a solution to the issue but found another issue. I have my media queries on another style sheet link(correctly) to the head of my html.For some reason on my 2nd style sheet use only for media queries it doesn't work but when I put it in the style sheet where al my non media queries is it works.

Comment: you have some issue with specificity, this rule is being overruled somewhere else, you need to be more specific , like `.parent .section {float:none}`,

Comment: thats what the problem was. thank you very much!!!! I started a month ago and i'm trying to figure it all out. sorry for the hassle